# There are no records from the database downloaded PHP MySQL, MVC

Tags: php, mysql, oop, model-view-controller

I have a problem downloading data from the database and even capture them to my view, but I think I have a foreach syntax error, but I can't understand that.

#### Model/model.php

```
    ...
    public function select($from, $select = '*', $where = NULL, $order = NULL, $limit = NULL) {

        $query = 'SELECT ' . $select . ' FROM ' . $from;
        if ($where != NULL)
             $query = $query.' WHERE '.$where;
        if ($order != NULL)
             $query = $query . ' ORDER BY ' . $order;
        if ($limit != NULL)
            $query = $query . ' LIMIT ' . $limit;

        $select = $this->pdo->query($query);
        foreach ($select as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
            //var_dump($data);
        }
        $select->closeCursor();

        return $data;
    }
}...
```

#### Model/categoy.php

```
...
    public function getAll() {
    var_dump($this->select('categories'));
    return $this->select('categories');
}
...
```

#### View/categories.php

```
<?php

    include 'View/view.php';

    class CategoriesView extends View{
        public function  index() {
            $cat = $this->loadModel('categories');
            $this->set('catsData', $cat->getAll());
            $this->render('indexCategory');
        }
        public function  add() {
            $this->render('addCategory');
        }
    }
```

#### indexCategory.html.php

```
    <h1>Lista kategorii</h1>
    <?php foreach($this->get('catsData') as $cats) { ?> <?php } ?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Nazwa</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><a href="?task=categories&action=delete&id=<?php echo $cats['id']; ?>">usun</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Link to my problem on my project - [click](http://jozwiak.edu.pl/index.php?task=categories&action=index).

Comment: your saying your trying to access the returned `$data` on your view right?    so on the view, its category.php?  and you have a method there `getAll()`?

Comment: No no, category.php is my model, sorry for this mistake. Please look now at my question

Comment: Ok i went off on the wrong tangent thinking about this then, so the problem is the 2nd model isnt returning the expected results, but it IS var_dumping them correctly for you right?  how are you trying to access them, to where your saying its broken?? Also they look alot better in `<pre>` tags if possible  (on your example) :-)

Comment: Yeah var_dump returning to me good result. I trying get this data with foreach on first model

Comment: in the select() method? or where, some code that you haven't shared yet?  oh ok, on the first model breaking, right.  ok lets see, i didn't see any problem there yet..  ok, so when you say var_dump, are you saying the var_dump in the first, or 2nd model is working correctly then??  i.e. which var dump works, BOTH in your code example, or which?

Comment: Other code does not correspond with me by displaying this data

Comment: I added my wiev to question can you look again?